# How to change Joomla date format in a component

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I would like to change the backend Joomla 3.0 date format for a custom component. Right now the component is taking the Joomla date backend format which is Y-m-d and that I need to change to d-m-Y for the custom component. I couldn't find where to change that format.

But one thing I found that the component date format code is coming from the following code:

```
<?php echo $item->date; ?>
```

And I would like to show the date in the following format:

```
echo date_format($date, 'd-m-Y H:i:s');
```

But don't know how I am going to implement it with the Joomla code. Need an idea on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the date using `JHtml` as shown below:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('date', $item->date, 'd-m-Y H:i:s'); ?>
```

So all you need to do is replace `<?php echo $item->date; ?>` with the above code

Answer (score 2):

You can use pre formated strings and change in language files ex.: /language/en-GB/en-GB.ini

DATE_FORMAT_LC="l, d F Y"

DATE_FORMAT_LC1="l, d F Y"

DATE_FORMAT_LC2="l, d F Y H:i"

DATE_FORMAT_LC3="d F Y"

DATE_FORMAT_LC4="d.m.y"

DATE_FORMAT_JS1="d-m-y"

Comment: I love you more than you know.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of J4 versions, I thought this may be of assistance to others.

```
use \Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use \Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;

echo HtmlHelper::date($date, Text::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC2'));
```